# nose-gae environment variable problems

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, nosetests

I'm trying to set up unit tests for a new Google App Engine Python application. For now I have a dummy tests.py file with this content:

```
import os
import unittest

from application import app


class LoginTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_login_request(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I run the test file with:
nosetests --with-gae tests.py

It fails with the error message: "ERROR: Failure: KeyError ('SERVER_SOFTWARE')". There's also a callstack and I see the culprit is gae_mini_profiler trying to read os.environ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]

I wonder if this is an error in gae_mini_profiler or nose-gae.

For a bit of background my app is based on the [Flask App Engine template](https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template). I got the exact same error when trying to run the sample unit test in the template with nose-gae.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the [NoseGAE](http://farmdev.com/projects/nosegae/) plugin installed.

And when I run Nose tests I use the following command-line switches:

```
--with-gae --without-sandbox
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue with one nuance:
 - When running the entire suite, I get no error
 - When targeting a specific module not in the root directory, I get the error. I'm thinking it is a bootstrapping issue, but I need to investigate more.